# Network Poisoning Outside ARP and DHCP

Tags: network, spoofing

If there is a firewall that can protect an infrastructure from ARP and DHCP poisoning attacks, are there any other protocols that I can spoof to poison the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARP spoofing and DHCP spoofing can only take place within a broadcast domain, so no firewall will protect against them (except insofar as it helps keep malicious people off machines in the broadcast domain).

Other equivalent vulnerabilities, such as [LLMNR and NBT-NS](https://www.surecloud.com/newsletter/local-network-vulnerabilities-llmnr-and-nbt-ns-poisoning) poisoning, are also limited to the broadcast domain.  By definition, any spoofing attack which relies upon the victim making a broadcast for information is going to be local to the broadcast domain.

DNS spoofing is one form of spoofing that is not limited by the broadcast domain; getting a bad record in any upstream DNS server or cache is sufficient.  Firewalls also lack any particular defense against this.